# Should we (still) expect people to read basic documentation before asking?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Should we expect people, in particular newbies, to at least read some documentation (and search slightly the web using some search engine) before asking any question?

I am an old guy (born in 1959) and I was educated with the idea that it is the minimal expectation to read some documentation before asking.

I believe that the ability to read (quickly) documentation is one of the most important skills of any software developer. FWIW, I learned Unix by reading the man pages from section 1 to section 8 (on paper, SunOS3, Sun3/160 workstation, 1987 or 88), in a time where I had access to Internet (from work) but there was no site like SO.

I feel that for young people (those asking questions here for the first few times, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51277230/841108) one), this is not the case anymore. It looks that RTFM is no more an important motto.

I believe that this explains my impression that the quality of questions and answers on SO has fallen tremendously since e.g. 2014 or before.

Is the "search by yourself before asking" (or "try to provide some MCVE" for code related questions) still a requirement on SO?

Maybe I am just tired, but I am more and more considering giving up my participation to SO.

If the answers (notably [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/841108) one) to [How Much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) are still relevant (but perhaps not anymore?) then I believe that a lot of recent questions should be closed (and then, the power to close questions should increase, or the cost to close them should decrease).

If searching somehow before asking is not required anymore, that is a drastic policy change on SO which should be *explicitly* documented (and then SO becomes more "Quora" like).

I feel that the expectation of reading documentation has (sadly) lowered a lot. If that is the case, the "How To Ask" and welcome messages to SO should evolve accordingly (and I would be less interested in SO).

This brings some suggestions for feature requests:

- lower the cost to downvote or close questions
- facilitate closing questions (e.g. lower threshold to be able to do that)
- improve the welcome and help windows.
- increase the size of the question text area, and suggest typing longer questions. Perhaps bring in some pop-up (or as a background text) some standard hints for newbies.
- if the policy regarding questions has changed, document that appropriately.

(On the other hand, I do understand that as a business, Stack Overflow needs traffic, even if the quality of its content is decreasing; I guess that those paying for job ads on SO don't care about the quality of questions here.)

Comment: No, not at all. and it doesn't matter how many people who dislike that leave, as there's plenty people joining in who want to play the game and earn points/feel good answering such useless questions.

Comment: You should fully expect users to not read anything, up to their own code.

Comment: @Braiam 'their own code'?  That's optimistic:(

Comment: As evidenced by the new blog post, any effort to ask users to read documentation is now deemed unwelcoming and can lead to being banned.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of saying "RTFM". I think there are ways you can recommend the documentation tactfully, regardless of how obvious the answer may seem. I've seem comments that are certainly trying to be helpful by pointing to the documentation that just come off as rude in a "I don't have time for this" kind of way.

Comment: It seems a little strange to me that the question you linked to as an example of one that shouldn't have been asked here due to lack of research effort has an answer from you. Did I misunderstand what that example was supposed to represent?

Comment: The standard answer is that there have *always* been poorly researched questions around.  A tag community can easily deal with that, as long as it is a trickle.  But it turned into a flood.  Not exactly at the same time for everybody.  [c++] survived longer than many others, might have something to do with it being a language used by professionals, poked only occasionally by students, and having a very stable community.  2013-14 were the pivotal years.  Another one is coming if the company's plans pan out, it is going to be worse.

Comment: One more suggestion would be to tackle the aspect that lazy questions are easy karma for those willing to indulge them. Maybe give a penalty if you answer a question instead of marking it as a duplicate or low effort?